# PopupWindow - not working on a few devices

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I use following code to show a small popup:

```
public static PopupWindow showImportMenu(Activity activity, View anchor, PopupWindowClickListener onClickListener)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

    PopupImportBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.popup_import, null, false);

    if (!RootTools.isRootAvailable())
        binding.llImportRootMethod.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity, null, R.attr.popupMenuStyle);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(popupWindow, anchor, 0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM);

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            onClickListener.onClick(popupWindow, view);
        }
    };

    binding.llImportDefault.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    binding.llImportRootMethod.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    binding.llImportHTCFromContacts.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    binding.llImportManual.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

This works on a lot of devices but on some rare devices it does not work, like:

- Android 5.1.1 root slim rom
- maybe others... until now, I don't know more about other devices

I got the feedback that no popup is shown. Does anyone know why this is not working on the above mentioned device? And what I can do to make it work on this device as well?

**EDIT**

It seems like it's not clear that what I want is following:

- use `showAsDropDown` not `showAtLocation` or similar, I never saw this problem with `showAtLocation` yet
- my solution is working on nearly all devices, it seems to be a phone/rom specific problem, maybe it's not even solvable as it COULD be a bug in the device as well => if someone knows of such a bug, telling me would be fine as well
- I don't want to use a dialog (or anything else) instead, that's not answering my question. I currently use a `BottomSheet` which is fine for me, but still I would like to know if the problem can be solved and somehow handled

Comment: Do you have stacktraces from that devices?

Comment: there's no crash on this device, it just does not show anything. But I requested the logcat, did not get one yet though

Comment: At least some system logs should appear.

Comment: why don't you ask him/her for video so you could check better way and would get good idea that what he/she doing and that is cause

Comment: Did you used showAtLocation? In some devices I saw that showAsDropDown is giving anchor position zero.

Comment: No. My experience is that `showAtLocation` is working as long as you provide a background drawable but I have not tried it on this special device because the user is not answering anymore. I want to have the advantages of `showAsDropDown` because my popup may need to be drawn on top, left, rigt, bottom or even overlaying the anchor depending on scroll position and screen size. Doing everything manually probably will work, but that's just an assumption, because in another app I never had problems with the `PopupWindow` and there I use `showAtLocation`...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Good new is I have the device where issue can be reproduced. I can confirm that `showAtLocation()`  does not help. `PopupWindow` is still not displayed. This is an Android 5.0.2 device from Vivo.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem on a Nexus 7 (not 2012) running the 5.1.1. It is finally fixed by adding this line:

```
popupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Any idea why this is needed only on some devices?

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed my problem API 19 - Galaxy note 3

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem: my `PopupWindow` was not showing on my 5.1.1 android device but it was on others. I realised that I had to specify the `width` and `height` in order to be shown on that version (which is still compatible with the rest of the versions as well).

Here is an example:

```
popUp.setWidth(MATCH_PARENT);
popUp.setHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, popup window have no sizes on few devices.

Try that after `setContentView`

`50000` - just a big size for measure.

```
    popupWindow.getContentView().measure(50000, 50000);
    popupWindow.setWidth(popupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredWidth());
    popupWindow.setHeight(popupWindow.getContentView().getMeasuredHeight());
```

You can use screen size instead 50000

Answer (score 1):

Some ROMs restrict usage of **popupview** with their own **permissions**. So user have to explicitly turn on permission to show pop up views.

Even **MIUI** will restrict **popupview** to be displayed by default.

Please have a look whether there is any permission in that ROMs or devices.

Comment: That's the only useable answer, thanks. Does this permission have a name? Can it be requested in the manifest or at runtime? Or can those people only manually give this permission somewhere in their system? Is it possible to test if the Rom needs permissions for a popup view? It's still weird that popup menus work though without problems.

Comment: That kind of permission is not included in android OS. So we can't use android requestpermission method to grant runtime permission. One option is that, we can navigate user to that permission screen.

Answer (score 0):

[image]## Ok i implemented popupwindow for sorting in my tab fragment and i checked working fine once try this

### I used in that custom layout for popup window

```
  final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popmenu1t1, null);
            l8[![enter image description here][1]][1] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.atoz);


  l8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    date_sort="0";
                    discount_sort="";
                    price_sort="";
                    alpha_sort="";
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
            int width = 900;
            int height = 400;
            try {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            popupWindow.setWidth(width*3/6);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popupWindow.setContentView(view);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

### Find the below attached screen shot popupwindow in my app

Answer (score 0):

I had created a custom popup dialog shows at bottom of screen

```
public class MoreOptionDialog {

private Dialog dialog;
private Context context;
private int size;

public MoreOptionDialog(Context context) {
    this.context = context;    
}

public void showMoreOptionDialog(List<String> listMoreOption) {

    dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DialogSlideAnim));
    dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_more_option, null);

    dialog.setContentView(view, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(utility.getScreenWidth() - 100, size));
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMoreOption);

    MoreOptionAdapter moreOptionAdapter = new MoreOptionAdapter(context, listMoreOption, Gravity.CENTER);
    listView.setAdapter(moreOptionAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            dialog.dismiss();                
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
}
```

And style is here

```
<style name="DialogSlideAnim">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

And this dialog working in all devices :)