# PopupWindow not inflating on API 19

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

My PopupWindow is working perfectly fine on my API 28,29 Emulators, but not sure why it's not showing any view on my API 19 real device. The window is definitely created though because when I click on the button that inflates the view, it is focused.

My custom popup window:

```
    public class MessagesMoreMenu extends PopupWindow {

    private static final String TAG = "MessagesMoreMenu";

    private Context mContext;
    public MessagesMoreMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        setupView();
    }

    private void setupView(){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.popupmenu_messagesmoremenu, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Usage of it:

```
    private void inflateMoreMenu(View view){
         PopupWindow popupWindow = new MessagesMoreMenu(mContext);
         popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
         popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
         popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
         popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);
    }
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popupmenu_messagesmore_report"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Report"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/icon_messages_report"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popupmenu_messagesmore_block"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Block"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/icon_alertdialog_block"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popupmenu_messagesmore_report"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you get any error. Try on a real device with API 28,29 or an emulator with API 19. Also, what is mContext here? Is it getApplicationContext() or ClassName.this?

Comment: classname.this and no errors

Comment: Please try on a real device with API 28,29 or an emulator with API 19. I will try to re-run the code on my end.

Comment: @davids.  please show your layout xml

Comment: @davids. give the RelativeLayout an exact `dp` or `match_parent` to try

Comment: try this solution:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673099/android-nougat-popupwindow-showasdropdown-gravity-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673099/android-nougat-popupwindow-showasdropdown-gravity-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird but adding this fixed my problem...

```
popupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177435/11110509

This is not needed on my other non API 19 devices

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
```

here mRelativeLayout is a view reference from your activity/fragment

Comment: tried, still not displaying on api 19. It works on the others though

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673099/android-nougat-popupwindow-showasdropdown-gravity-not-working